# NodeJS Periodic tasks

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

Firts of all, I'll explain my problem:

I'm developing an ecommerce website. One of it features is the possibility for the customers to create *purchasing rules*. With these rules a customer can set a start date, a periodicity and a product to purchase. The result is that the product will be purchased every *[periodicity]* days from *[start date]*.

The system is developed with NodeJS as back-end, MongoDB as database and AngularJS as front-end.

I've found some projects for scheduling tasks in NodeJS. Two of them are:

- [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)
- [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron)

Both of them are great tools but I have the same problem with the two of them. The problem is that I need to create scheduled tasks as well as stop them. With these tools is very clear how to schedule a function to be executed over time, but how can I stop them at any moment?

The objects provided by node-schedule and node-cron have a cancel() or stop() method to stop the scheduling, but to invoke that method I need to have the object.

My question is if there is a way to "store" the scheduled tasks in database in order to be able to stop them at any moment and from anywhere other than the function they were created.

And if this is not possible, if there is another tool better than those I've mentioned to do what I need.

Thank you very much for reading and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this agenda(https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), i didn't used it, but it allows you to save schedule tasks in chosen databases like MongoDB or redis. Also, why cannot you create a simple program to save your tasks in database and create a child processes to continuously run, check and execute your operations. It is just an advice. If you are interested, i am happy to contribute, because, i and others may need it. Any way, lets wait for other people comments, they might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that package is just what I need. You made my day. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a better solution for my problem than adding a bunch of scheduled task, one for purchasing rule. Now my purchasing_rules table looks like this:

```
+--------------------+
|   purchase_rules   |
+--------------------+
| customer_id        |
| product_id         |
| quantity           |
| start_date         |
| periodicity (Days) |
+--------------------+
```

My solution is  to add the field next run, so my table will look like:

```
+--------------------+
|   purchase_rules   |
+--------------------+
| customer_id        |
| product_id         |
| quantity           |
| start_date         |
| periodicity (Days) |
| next_run           |
+--------------------+
```

By default [next_run] will be [start_date] + [periodictiy].

And now, the magic:

I will use [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) to schedule a job every day at a certain hour. That job will do the following:

1. Look in the purchase_rules table for any rule whose next_run = today
2. For every rule  found:

   1. Purchase the desired [quantity] of product [product_id] for the customer [customer_id]
   2. Make [next_run] = [next_run] + [periodicity]
3. Finish

This way the database will not be accesed as many times as with the Agenda package and for "stopping" a purchasing_rule I only have to remove it from database.

I hope someone will find this useful some day.